# Connect SSL Cert to Route53 Hosted Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https

For some reason I cannot find a yes or no if this is even possible but I am assuming that it would be. I have a domain through AWS that was purchased through AWS Route53. I also created an SSL Cert through AWS Certificate Manager. Now I'm just trying to add that certificate to the domain. I would think that since it is all interconnected that it would just been applied after I approved it and it finished the setup but alas, it has not. So my question is how/where do I connect my SSL Cert to my Route53 hosted domain?

Comment: Certificates aren't attached to domains, they're installed on servers or load balancers. If you're using an ELB, you specify the certificate when setting up the HTTPS listener.

Comment: Cool. Well I'm going to leave this question in even though it got downvoted cause when I researched for two hours nobody on the web could say yes or no you cannot just connect an SSL Cert to your hosted website through Route53 like you can with a cheap site and cert through GoDaddy. This may keep someone from wasting two hours of their life as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL certificates are not connected to a domain's DNS record (via Route 53).

Instead, they are connected to one or more specific infrastructure components.

SSL certificates that you create from ACM can be used with:

- AWS Elastic Load Balancer
- AWS CloudFront

Create your infrastructure including one or more of those components and then attach your ACM SSL certificate to that.

See the ACM FAQ: https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/

Comment: Connected a cloudfront distro to the site but CloudFront wants to connect to an S3 Bucket and this is actually a domain for an EC2 instance that is running a CI server on it. Will see if that works once it is finished setting up.

Comment: CloudFront can use S3 buckets or any other web server as a content origin.

Comment: Yeah see that. So basically, I have a CI server that is running on an EC2 instance and need that to have SSL. From what I am seeing that is not possible by itself. So need to have that EC2 instance going to an ELB or to CloudFront.

Comment: Using an ACM SSL certification, yes, you must use CloudFront or ELB. Otherwise, you need to get an SSL certificate using other ways (like through GoDaddy, etc.)

Comment: Got it taken care of. Thanks for the help @Matt Houser